# How to get response body in Zuul post filter?

Tags: java, proxy, netflix-zuul

How it is possible to read a response body while using Zuul as a proxy in `post` filter?

I am trying to call the code like this:

```
@Component
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostFilter.class);

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 2000;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        ctx.getResponseBody(); // null

        // cant't do this, cause input stream is used later in other filters and I got InputStream Closed exception
        // GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(stream);
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've managed to overcome this. The solution consists of 4 steps:

1. Read `ctx.getResponseDataStream()` into a ByteArrayOutputStream
2. Copy OutputStream to 2 InputStreams.
3. Use one of it for your custom purposes.
4. Use the second to reassign to context: `context.setResponseBody(inputStream)`

   - reading stream from point 1 would cause that the stream cannot be read again, so this way you're passing a new fresh stream that wasn't read yet

Comment: Don't remember exactly, but probably yes. Did you copied inputstream?

Comment: Copying the `InputStream` worked great, but I had to set my filter order before `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter`. Using anything greater than 1000 leads to an "InputStream already closed" error because the response body has already been read and returned.

Comment: Ok, good. The number I used in example was probably not so important for my question ;)

Comment: @MichaelTecourt the filter number should be part of the response. I was trying for hours, just changed the filter number to 10 and it worked

Answer (score 11):

If someone is struggling with compressed answer, here's the solution I used:

```
// Read the compressed response
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
InputStream compressedResponseDataStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream();
try {
    // Uncompress and transform the response
    InputStream responseDataStream = new GZIPInputStream(compressedResponseDataStream);
    String responseAsString = StreamUtils.copyToString(responseDataStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    // Do want you want with your String response
    ...
    // Replace the response with the modified object
    ctx.setResponseBody(responseAsString);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.warn("Error reading body", e);
}
```

Comment: if you using gzip as html compress process

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for suggestion, this is the code I used that works.

```
try (final InputStream responseDataStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream()) {
   final String responseData = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(responseDataStream, "UTF-8"));
   ctx.setResponseBody(responseData);
} catch (IOException e) {
   logger.warn("Error reading body",e);
}
```

Comment: Nice use of Java 7's try-with-resources syntax here. In case someone is worried about `CharStreams.toString()` being `@Beta` (IntelliJ warns about it), one could also use Spring's `StreamUtils.copyToString()` if it's a dependency. This way, one can also omit the `InputStreamReader` instance. Also, imho it's a bit cleaner to use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `"UTF-8"`.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in this [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/filters/post/SendResponseFilter.java), you have two methods available to extract the response body:

1- ctx.getResponseBody();

2- ctx.getResponseDataStream();

You have to check which one is not null and use that one.

Comment: Thanks, I already did id, but it was a little bit tricky. I'll post some code

Comment: in my case, ctx.getResponseBody(); return null so i used ctx.getResponseDataStream(); instead

Comment: just found that `delete` has `ctx.getResponseBody()` but `post` and `put` has `getResponseDataStream()`

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with the filterNumber

> Using anything greater than 1000 leads to an "InputStream already
>   closed" error because the response body has already been read and

I used the number 10 and worked fine

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me. 
1) Order of the filter needs to be lower that 1000 (sending response filter)

2) Code:

```
 private String getResponseData(RequestContext ctx) throws IOException {
    String responseData = null;

    final InputStream responseDataStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream copy = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    while ((read = responseDataStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
        bos.write(buff, 0, read);
        copy.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    InputStream isFromFirstData = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());

    boolean responseGZipped = ctx.getResponseGZipped();
    try {
        InputStream zin = null;
        if (responseGZipped) {
            zin = new GZIPInputStream(isFromFirstData);
        } else {
            zin = responseDataStream;
        }
        responseData = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(zin, "UTF-8"));
        ctx.setResponseDataStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(copy.toByteArray()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Error reading body {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    return responseData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to get an input stream, read it with `InputStreamReader`, and finally create a new stream based on the read string and set it as a response data stream of context. Also, don't forget to set the order of the filter to number lower then 1000.

```
final InputStream responseDataStream = ctx.getResponseDataStream();
String response = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(responseDataStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
ctx.setResponseDataStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//NOTE:filterOrder:999
RequestContext context = getCurrentContext();
InputStream stream = context.getResponseDataStream();
// uncompress
String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(new GZIPInputStream(stream),
    Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

// modify
body = "Modified gzipped response via setResponseBody(): " + body;

// compress again
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(body.length());
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
gzip.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"));
gzip.close();
byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
bos.close();
context.setResponseDataStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
```

https://github.com/spring-attic/sample-zuul-filters/issues/4