# How to get Response Body in Zuul?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

How to get Response Body in Zuul?

So I have the ff. code snippet to get the response body in a request.

```
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

getResponseDataStream
getResponseBody()
ctx.getResponse()
```

But all of this are returning null. I already tried those InputStreams, but I can't get it to retrive the data as all of it just returns null..

Answer (score 0):

Try something from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088498/how-to-get-response-body-in-zuul-post-filter) answer. It should be access via `getResponseDataStream()` or `getResponseBody()`. If you do it in `ZuulFilter` in 'post' keep the higher value for `filterOrder`. Maybe it was not written yet. For example:

```java
public class PostFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return POST_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return SEND_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1;
    }
```